# Linux - Copiar apenas atributos de arquivos em uma pasta

Tags: linux, backup, linha-de-comando, atributos

Do começo... Tive um problema com meu particionamento e precisei zerar minha HD. Estou rodando Linux Mint 19 em Live-CD (USB) para poder copiar o conteúdo da minha pasta /home (que estava em outra partição - /dev/sda6 - e montei em /mnt) para um HD externo. Para isso, usei o comando:

`cp -r /mnt/user /media/mint/Samsung\ M3/BKP/Linux/home/user -v`.

Resultado: todos os arquivos foram copiados com sucesso. Porém, eles não vieram com as devidas permissões, atributos, owners e etc.

Tem como eu recuperar essas informações (copiar apenas os atributos dos arquivos originais para os do backup já existentes)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quando for necessário copiar as informações de donos e grupos do arquivo deve-se usar o parâmetro `-p` , no seu caso o comando para realizar a cópia dos arquivos e manter as permissões seria:

```
cp -rp /mnt/user /media/mint/Samsung\ M3/BKP/Linux/home/user -v
```

Mais detalhes do comando cp pode ser visto no próprio terminal com o comando `man cp`